# Why can't I use [HttpPost] instead [HttpPost("[action]")]?

Tags: asp.net-core, routes

I don't understand why I need to use `[HttpPost("[action]")]` instead of `[HttpPost]`?

If use `[HttpPost("[action]")]` then the request from angular client hits the controller action.

```
// POST: api/LeaveRequests
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostLeaveRequest([FromBody] LeaveRequest leaveRequest)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    _context.LeaveRequests.Add(leaveRequest);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetLeaveRequest", new { id = leaveRequest.EmployeeNo }, leaveRequest);
}
```

But
If I only put `[HttPost]` then the request from anglular client does not hit controller action and instead it hits method with the path `[HttpGet("{id}")]`

My MVC route

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                    name: "spa-fallback",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            });
```

my angular http.post

```
return this.http.post(this._apiUrl, body, options)
    .map(res => res.json()) // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
    .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'))
    .subscribe();
```

Comment: You need to specify a path. You can also put `[HttpPost("yourpath\{id}\something")]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This `[HttpPost("blah blah")]` is for defining route [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.httppostattribute)

Alternatively you can use `Attribute routing` [Read this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("PostLeaveRequest")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostLeaveRequest([FromBody] LeaveRequest leaveRequest)
{
 ..................................

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in dotnet core and as above - it is used in routing templates with attribute replacement.

[Link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area)